# WooCommerce - Order Status for Pending Payment Reducing Stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use WooCommerce to manually take orders via the telephone / email etc. I use the backend to record the orders manually adding the orders.

At present, when generating an order as 'pending payment' as the status the stock is automatically reduced / deducted. I do not want this to happen. Ideally I only want stock to be reduced when the order is marked as in 'processing' as then payment would of then been taken.

I understand this is how WooCommerce works back is there a way to avoid stock being reduced until a certain status has been selected?

I have tried the below code within functions.php and used the 'on-hold' status to test but the stock is still reduced.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 'wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock', 10, 2 );
function wcs_do_not_reduce_onhold_stock( $reduce_stock, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( 'on-hold' )) {
        $reduce_stock = false;
    }
    return $reduce_stock;
}
```

I wonder if it because I am adding the order as an admin? I know this is how WooCommerce works but ideally I need a method of overriding the 'pending payment' status when creating an order both within the draft and creation stage until marked as 'processing'.

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this adding to functions.php
**Note: not tested.**

```
function reduce_stock_processing($order_id) {
 wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);
```

}

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'reduce_stock_processing');
```